# How does one see all tokens owned by an account?

Tags: tokens, erc-20

Sorry, I do not understand this very well. But with tokens (let's say those which follow ERC20), can one ethereum address own multiple tokens? How would one determine the names and balances of those tokens using JSON RPC or web3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can one ethereum address own multiple tokens?

Yes, any ethereum can own multiple tokens.

> How would one determine the names and balances of those tokens using
>   JSON RPC or web3?

You will need contract ABI and address of each contract to check balances. You can implement something like this:

```
var contarct1 = web3.eth.contract(contract1_abi).at(contract1_address);
var contarct2 = web3.eth.contract(contract2_abi).at(contract2_address);
var balance1 = contract1.balanceOf(accountAddr).toNumber();
var balance2 = contract2.balanceOf(accountAddr).toNumber();
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this in the JSON RPC? I'm not seeing methods like `web3.eth.contract()` in the wiki.

Comment: Have a look at documentation : https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract

Comment: It seems that's just for the JavaScript API. Is the eth.contract method exposed via JSON RPC?

Comment: Yes. It is exposed over Json RPC. I have used it and it works good

Comment: @PrashantPrabhakarSingh is there way to get list of available erc20 tokens  on ethereum blockchain?.